# reading in strings and doubles

Tags: c++, string, double

I'm having an issue reading in a string from a file and then a double from a file afterwards.  My professor advised me to put a special getline after each input line, but it hasn't worked and I've deduced that this is the issue with the program.  Is there a simpler way to take in doubles?

example of the input file is:

```
John Smith
019283729102380
300.00
2000.00
Andrew Lopez
293481012100121
400.00
1500.00
```

the code reads:

```
while(! infile.eof())
{
getline(infile,accname[count],'\n');
getline(infile, refuse, '\n');  
getline(infile,accnum[count],'\n');
getline(infile, refuse, '\n');  
infile>>currbal[count];  
getline(infile, refuse, '\n');  
infile>>credlim[count];  
getline(infile, refuse, '\n');  
count++;
}
```

Comment: What didn't work?  What input did you give it, and what happened?

Comment: @Oli, It really just froze the program, and then I commented out the "refuses" and the infiles pertaining to doubles, and it ran (while outputting garbage)

Comment: What does your input file look like?

Comment: it is just lines of information in the pattern of: string, string, double, double

Comment: @Sam - can you post a two-line sample of your input file?

Comment: Only partly related: `while(!infile.eof()) { /* read data */ }` is almost certainly a bug. Not *the* bug, but *a* bug.

Comment: Yeah:
John Smith                                               019283729102380

Comment: theres a newline where the space is

Comment: @Rob, are you sure?  It has worked before?  Or is it wrong in practice

Comment: Can you possibly tell me which C++ book told you to use the eof() function? Then I can go out an assassinate the author. And if you can't tell me which book you got it from why are you using it?

Comment: @Sam, yes, that is a bug. `infile.eof()` cannot predict that the upcoming read will encounter an EOF. Consider [this program](http://ideone.com/qPkCO). After it correctly reads "3", it stops at the final newline. Since the EOF bit has not yet been set, it tries to read the value after "3", and bad things happen.

Comment: @Sam - I'm sorry, I still don't understand what the input is. Could you edit your question to include a sample of the input in a code block, with the precise spacing and newlines that you expect? So that we can see the pattern, please include two cycles of data. Thanks.

Comment: @unapersson,  I didn't read it anywhere, my professor had taught it, what is a better way to go about that task then?  @Rob, I posted an example.

Comment: @Sam - I notice that you double-spaced your sample input. I assume that your actual input is single-spaced, and updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: Updated in response to OP's clarification.

Based on the sample you provided, this should work:

```
while(1) {
    std::string s1;
    if(!std::getline(infile, s1))
        break;
    std::string s2;
    if(!std::getline(infile, s2))
        break;
    double d1, d2;
    if(!(infile >> d1 >> d2))
        break;
    accname[count] = s1;
    accnum[count] = s2;
    currball[count] = d1;
    credlim[count] = d2;
    count++;
}
```

This code will work for input like:

```
Adam Sandler
0112233
5 100
Ben Stein
989898
100000000
1
```

But it won't work for input like:

```
Adam Sandler

0112233

5 100

Ben Stein

989898

100000000

1
```

Answer (score 0):

I think Rob Adams's, response has a minor bug when parsing multiple records. After extracting `d2` for the first time, the example input stream will contain `\nBen Stein\n989898\n100000000\n1`, therefore the next call to `std::getline()` will extract an empty string instead of `Ben Stein`. So it seems necessary to consume an empty string at the end of each while loop iteration.

I think the following code sample provides a fix:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  using std::stringstream;
  stringstream infile(stringstream::in | stringstream::out);

  infile << "John Smith\n";
  infile << "019283729102380\n";
  infile << "300.00\n";
  infile << "2000\n";
  infile << "Andrew Lopez\n";
  infile << "293481012100121\n";
  infile << "400.00\n";
  infile << "1500.00\n";

  std::string account_name;
  std::string account_number;
  double current_balance;
  double credit_limit;

  int count = 0;

  while (std::getline(infile, account_name) &&
         std::getline(infile, account_number) >> current_balance >>
         credit_limit) {

    std::cout << account_name << std::endl;
    std::cout << account_number << std::endl;
    std::cout << current_balance << std::endl;
    std::cout << credit_limit << std::endl;

    /*
    accname[count] = account_name;
    accnum[count] = account_number;
    currball[count] = current_balance;
    credlim[count] = credit_limit;
    */

    count++;

    // Consume the leading newline character, which seprates the credit limit
    // from the next account name, when infile contains multiple records.
    //
    // For example, after consuming the record for John Smith, the stream will
    // contain: "\nAndrew Lopez\n293481012100121\n400.00\n1500.00\n". If you
    // don't consume the leading newline character, calling std::getline() to
    // parse the next account name will extract an empty string.
    std::string blank;
    std::getline(infile, blank);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string str;

while(!infile.eof())
{
    getline(infile, accname[count]);//  you do not need '\n' it will always read to 
                     // end of the line

    getline(infile, accnum[count]);

    getline(infile, str);
    currbal[count] = atof(str.c_str());

    getline(infile, str);
    credlim[count] = atof(str.c_str());

    count++;
}

\* 
for the file 
John Smith
019283729102380
300.00
2000.00
Andrew Lopez
293481012100121
400.00
1500.00
*\
```